# How to handle uploaded videos and stream videos in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, video-streaming

Users upload videos (max 50MB) which I am currently storing in file system
Then my video processing job grabs the file and processes it to target file type (flv)
The processed file then pushed to gridFS and streaming on a page

I need to keep the original video in case in future I have to reconvert them to different format (if we decide to go HTML5)

I am wondering if it would be better to save the uploaded video in MongoDB gridFS as well instead of file system.

My question is:
Am I using the right design for video streaming from a site built on MongDB database?

If you have BKM, could you please share your 2 cents.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have a reason to store the videos in a database?

Comment: No reason. I am trying to see if gridFS is a viable storage for video streaming.

Comment: You should upload the original video to GridFS too, then you'll get the same replication's security and high availability to both documents.

Comment: I don't need availability to the original video. As long as I have one format saved, I can get the other formats from it.

Comment: you can get the other formats as long as you have one video, but each conversion **will** damage the video quality. If this is not a problem for your application, then you don't need to store the original video.

Comment: WHy not save the original video in gridfs then convert it on the fly when streaming